# classregtree building tree algorithm documentation

Tags: matlab

I used `classregtree` to buid a tree and I need to know the algorithm behind building that tree, I read `classregtree` matlab page but it doesn't say any details. Also I check the reference paper but I couldn't find it. Any advice?

Comment: Read the official documentation page and scroll to the bottom: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classregtree.html - It references a very well known and seminal textbook: *Breiman, L., J. Friedman, R. Olshen, and C. Stone. Classification and Regression Trees. Boca Raton, FL: CRC Press, 1984.*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`classregtree` uses an implementation of the C&RT algorithm. As @rayryeng mentions in a comment, the main reference for this is the book "Classification and Regression Trees" by Breiman, Friedman, Olshen and Stone.

Note that `classregtree` is being deprecated by MathWorks over the next few releases, and you're encouraged to move toward `ClassificationTree` and `RegressionTree`, which also use (slightly different) implementations of C&RT.